# Jekyll site.categories incorrect values

Tags: jekyll

When I access `site.categories.first` I get what looks to be all the content of all my blog posts wrapped into a single string.

When I access `site.categories[1]` I get an empty string. The length of `site.categories` appears roughly equal to the number of categories I have.

I checked for any manual editing of `site.categories`, but I don't see anything that would be doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `inspect` filter to understand how categories works.

`{{ site.categories | inspect }}` returns a hash like:

```
{
"jekyll"=>[#<Jekyll::Document _posts/2017-10-31-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown collection=posts>], 
"update"=>[#<Jekyll::Document _posts/2017-10-31-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown collection=posts>]
}
```

And `{{ site.categories.first | inspect }}` returns an array like :

```
["jekyll", [#<Jekyll::Document _posts/2017-10-31-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown collection=posts>]]
```

Where `{{ site.categories.first[0] }}` is the category name, and `{{ site.categories.first[1] }}` is an array containing first category's document.

You can call a category from his name `{{ site.categories.jekyll | inspect }}` but not by is index `{{ site.categories[0] | inspect }} => []`

You cannot modify `site.categories` because it is `freezed` by jekyll.

Comment: I figured out what I was doing wrong through a lot of trial and error. This is a way better answer than what I was going to post this morning!